# Single line code is hidden by the horizontal scrollBar

Tags: bug, design, markdown, code-formatting

The horizontal ScrollBar on a one line code on any post is hiding the code for me.

I'm using Google Chrome 71.0.3578.98 on [macOS v10.14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Mojave) (Mojave), but I think this bug is a general issue. And here are some examples:

1- First example: once you use the horizontal scrollbar, it will hide the line of code.

```
>>> code simple code lorum ipsum code simple code lorum ipsum code simple code lorum ipsum ; # just some code
```

2- Second Example, an image from another Stack Exchange site

[image: Example]

I hope this simple bug will be fixed and thanks.